# Extracting some nodes from XML Files

Tags: java, xml

I need to extract some nodes from an XML file formatted in this way:

```
<collection sentiment="negativo">
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
     <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>blabla</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
  </comment>
```

Now assume that there are other `<comment>` elemente that have `<lang>spanish</lang>` in the same XML file. 
I need to create two separate XML files. The first one with ALL THE NODES  having the child `<lang>english</lang>` (let's call it eng.xml) and the second one having `<lang>spanish</lang>` (let's call it spa.xml)

Here is my JAVA code:

```
public void getEnglishRows() throws IOException{
    OutputStreamWriter f = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/eclipse/neg_eng.xml"));
    BufferedWriter buff;

    NodeList current_row = doc.getElementsByTagName("comment"); //Mette in una lista tutti i nodi row (che contengono a loro volta degli elementi)
    NodeList tmp;
    Node nodo = null;

    buff = new BufferedWriter(f);
    for(int i=0;i< current_row.getLength();i++){
        tmp = current_row.item(i).getChildNodes();
        for(int k=0;k<tmp.getLength();k++){
            nodo = tmp.item(k);

            if("english".equals(nodo.getTextContent()))
                System.out.println("IF ENGLISH");
                buff.write(current_row.item(i).getNodeValue());                         
        }
    }


    buff.close();
}
```

I don't know if I was clear, I hope so.

So I've ONE Xml files with LOTS of `<comment></comment>` . I've to extract from this ALL the `<comment></comment>` that have `<lang>english</lang>` and write the node  (with it's childs) to another XML file. Same behaviour for `<lang>spanish</lang>`.

The output of eng.xml is:

```
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
     <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>blabla</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
  </comment>
```

The output of spa.xml is:

```
 <comment>
        <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
         <chars>...</chars>
        <words>...</words>
        <text>blabla</text>
        <lang>spanish</lang>
      </comment>
```

I hope I'm clear. My problem is that I can extract the text of all nodes, but it does not mantain the XML tags!!

Please help me!

Comment: look into jaxb or xstream

Comment: Ok I'll dig into this. I'd like also some example of code :)
Thanks a lot!
EDIT: Xstrem is just to serialize object into XML, I already have an XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to delete comments that are not in english ?
So my suggestion was to search for  tags and detect the not-english ones. Then go to the parent element that contains the node (the  element) and delete it. This preserves the original file structure.

Try this code. It worked for me :)

```
public void getEnglishRows() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException{      
    OutputStreamWriter f = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("./eng_sent.xml"));
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream("C:/eclipse/neg_eng.xml"));

    NodeList current_row = doc.getElementsByTagName("lang"); // search for the lang element

    for(int i=0;i< current_row.getLength();i++){            
        String lang = current_row.item(i).getTextContent();

        if (!lang.equalsIgnoreCase("english")) {
            // delete not english comment
            Element comment = (Element) current_row.item(i).getParentNode();
            doc.getDocumentElement().removeChild(comment);
            doc.normalize();
        }           
    }

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
    transformer.transform(source, result);      
}
```

The file neg_eng will appears like the following:

```
<collection sentiment="negativo">
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>eng3</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
</comment>
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>eng1</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
</comment>
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>eng2</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
</comment>
```

where the original xml file was:

```
<collection sentiment="negativo">
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>eng3</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
</comment>
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>spa2</text>
    <lang>spanish</lang>
</comment>
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>eng1</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
</comment>
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>eng2</text>
    <lang>english</lang>
</comment>
<comment>
    <sentiment> ...</sentiment>
    <chars>...</chars>
    <words>...</words>
    <text>spa1</text>
    <lang>spanish</lang>
</comment>
```

Hope this will help you!
Happy Hacking ;-)

Comment: Thanks Rob! I'll try this evening! +100! HH!